# App Engine Connected Android Storing images to Google Datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've searched for quite a while and can not find a simple tutorial on uploading a image to the GAE Datastore from the Android Connected App Engine project auto generated code the Google plugin provides in eclipse. It auto generates code for the image but i am unsure how to use it. I can upload the primitive datatypes fine and have been using this fairly easily. I was hoping there was an equally easy example on uploading the images.

I have edited some of the app engine code but i'm not to familiar with it so i was hoping to just use the generated code without to many serious changes.

Basically, I want to create a new table of images and store a list of keys to those images in a JDO object. I was hoping someone could lead me down the right track with a known tutorial using the auto generated code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably stores images in google cloud storage, rather then the datastore.  Also you can probably just upload the files directly to the GCS service rather then uploading to your app first.

Comment: Ill take a look into that. Still new to this and I need to have this part done tonight. It was the last piece of the puzzle and I keep putting it off because I can not find a solution.